# Print executed command for Python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

I have a script that is automating author re-writes on a number of git repositories.

```
def filter_history(old, new, name, repoPath):

command = """--env-filter '
        an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
        cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "|old|" ]]
        then
            cn="|name|"
            cm="|new|"
        fi

        if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "|old|" ]]
        then
            an="|name|"
            am="|new|"
        fi

        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
'
"""

#DO string replace
command = command.replace("|old|", old)
command = command.replace("|new|", new)
command = command.replace("|name|", name)

print "git filter-branch -f " + command

process = subprocess.Popen(['git filter-branch -f', command],cwd=os.path.dirname(repoPath), shell=True)
process.wait()
```

The command executes fine, but tells me that nothing changed in the repo history.  However, if I take the command that is printed out (which should be what is being executed), drop it in a shell script, and execute it, it changes the history fine.  I think that the command is somehow not being executed correctly.  Is there any way for be to see exactly what command the subprocess module is executing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `shell = True`, `subprocess.Popen` expects a string as its first argument. It is better not to use `shell = True` if you can help it, since it can be a [security risk (see the Warning](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

When you omit `shell = True`, or use `shell = False`, `subprocess.Popen` expects a list of arguments. You can generate that list of arguments from a string using `shlex.split`:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

def filter_history(old, new, name, repoPath):
    """Change author info
    """
    # http://help.github.com/change-author-info/
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/3880493/190597
    command = """git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
        an="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"
        am="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"
        cn="$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"
        cm="$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"

        if [[ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "{old}" ]]
        then
            cn="{name}"
            cm="{new}"
        fi

        if [[ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "{old}" ]]
        then
            an="{name}"
            am="{new}"
        fi

        export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$an"
        export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$am"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$cn"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$cm"
      '
      """.format(old = old, new = new, name = name)

    process = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(command),
        cwd = os.path.dirname(repoPath))
    process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your application is running in a Windows environment, as stated in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837250/6853432), subprocess has an undocumented function called `subprocess.list2cmdline` which you could use. `subprocess.list2cmdline` translates a sequence of arguments into a command line string, using the same rules as the MS C runtime.

if you are using Python > 3.3 you could also get the args list directly from the subprocess object using `.args`:

```py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(...)
subprocess.list2cmdline(process.args)
```

Since Python 3.8 there is also a possibility to use the [`shlex.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.join) function:

Keep in mind though that subprocess does everything via IPC, so the best approach would be to simply examine the `args` list, as they will be passed to `argv` in the called program.