# '^' is ignored by Python - how to escape '^' character in Popen Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, imagemagick, subprocess

I prepared some code to execute such command line:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\convert "c:\root\dropbox\www\tiff\photos\architecture\calendar-bwl-projekt\bwl01.tif" -thumbnail 352x352^ -format jpg -filter Catrom -unsharp 0x1 "c:\root\dropbox\www\tiff\thumbnails\architecture\calendar-bwl-projekt\thumbnail\bwl01.jpg"
```

This works fine from command line (same command as above) but 352x352^ is 352x352^ not 352x352:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\convert "c:\root\dropbox\www\tiff\photos\architecture\calendar-bwl-projekt\bwl01.tif" -thumbnail 352x352^ -format jpg -filter Catrom -unsharp 0x1 "c:\root\dropbox\www\tiff\thumbnails\architecture\calendar-bwl-projekt\thumbnail\bwl01.jpg"
```

If run this code from Python, the `^` character is ignored and the resized image has size as  if '%sx%s' was passed instead of %sx%s^

Why does Python cut out the `^` character and how can I avoid it?

```
def resize_image_to_jpg(input_file, output_file, size):
  resize_command = 'c:\\cygwin\\bin\\convert "%s" -thumbnail %sx%s^ -format jpg -filter Catrom -unsharp 0x1 "%s"' \
                   % (input_file, size, size, output_file)
  print resize_command
  resize = subprocess.Popen(resize_command)
  resize.wait()
```

Comment: Try passing a list to `Popen` instead of a string. That helps sometimes.

Comment: @Kevin No matter see module code bellow list will be joined.

Comment: unrelated: `Popen(cmd).wait()` is what `subprocess.call(cmd)` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why Python cuts '^' character and how to avoid it?

Python does not cut `^` character. `Popen()` passes the string (`resize_command`) to `CreateProcess()` Windows API call as is.

It is easy to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-c', 'import sys; print(sys.argv)'] +
                      ['^', '<-- see, it is still here'])
```

The latter command uses `subprocess.list2cmdline()` that follows [Parsing C Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx) rules to convert the list into the command string -- it has not effect on `^`.

[`^` is not special for `CreateProcess()`. `^` is special if you use `shell=True` (when `cmd.exe` is run)](http://www.daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm#WINCRULESCHANGE).

[**if and only if** the command line produced will be interpreted by cmd, prefix each shell metacharacter (or each character) with a `^` character](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx). It includes `^` itself.

Comment: If I'm following this correctly, the problem is actually the opposite of what's specified in the question - the `^` is dropped when the command is typed at the command line, but preserved when using `Popen`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes. `^` escapes the next character on the command line but it has no special meaning if `Popen()` is used without `shell=True`. My guess either OP hasn't provided the actual code (i.e., `shell=True` is used) or the `convert` command corrupts the arguments itself.

Comment: I was added shell=True tp remove problem - now I understand the root cause better - very good explanation.

Comment: @eryksun: To be clear: the answer does not recommend `shell=True`. It just says that without `shell=True` (no interpretation by `cmd.exe`), `^` is not special i.e., `^` is passed as is to the command.