# Python subprocess.check_output(args) fails, while args executed via Windows command line work OK

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

Some problems with python [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

```
output = subprocess.check_output(args)
```

where my `args` is:

```
args = "C:\\DO\\bin\\Config.exe --ChCfg7 --LFE -b1152000 C:\\DO\\PCM\\1.wav C:\\DO\\PCM\\2.wav C:\\DO\\PCM\\3.wav C:\\DO\\PCM\\4.wav C:\\DO\\PCM\\5.wav C:\\DO\\PCM\6.wav --ModeBCast -oC:\\DO\\OUT\\outfile > C:\\DO\\OUT\\log.txt
```

This works when executed from standard windows command line, but doesn't work when executed via Python `subprocess.check_output`. In win cmd case there is output file produced and log.txt too, and python script produces out file with size 0, and no log.txt at all.

Comment: Use   raw string  `r"C:\DO....` when dealing with file paths or use  `/`. You also need shell=True for a string of args.

Comment: r? Once before `args` or before every path within `ąrgs`?

Comment: To be clear, you can use `r"C:\path\file"` or `"C:\\path\\file"`, it's just a little easier to read if you use `r""`.

Comment: `shell=True` resolved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
output = subprocess.check_output(args,shell=True)
```

Run this with `shell=True`

Answer (score 2):

Use a list of args  and redirect the output to a file:

```
import subprocess

args = ['C:/DO/bin/Config.exe', '--ChCfg7', '--LFE', '-b1152000', 'C:/DO/PCM/1.wav', 'C:/DO/PCM/2.wav', 'C:/DO/PCM/3.wav', 'C:/DO/PCM/4.wav', 'C:/DO/PCM/5.wav', 'C:/DO/PCM/6.wav', '--ModeBCast', '-oC:/DO/OUT/outfile']

with open("C:/DO/OUT/log.txt", "w") as f:
    subprocess.check_call(args, stdout=f)
```

You can use `shell=True`but for [security reasons](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) generally it is not a very good idea and the same can be quite easily achieved using the code above and simply redirecting the output to the file.

Answer (score 0):

`>` is a shell redirection operator. Either run the command in a shell or (better) as [@Padraic Cunningham suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450855/4279) emulate it in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

args = r"C:\DO\bin\Config.exe --ChCfg7 --LFE -b1152000".split()
args += [r'C:\DO\PCM\%d.wav' % i for i in range(1, 7)]
args += ["--ModeBCast", r"-oC:\DO\OUT\outfile"]    
with open(r"C:\DO\OUT\log.txt", "wb", 0) as output_file:
    subprocess.check_call(args, stdout=output_file)
```

The code uses raw string literals for Windows paths to avoid escaping backslashes.

There is usually no point to use `shell=True` on Windows unless you want to run a built-in command such as `dir`. If `args` is not constructed using input from an external source then [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations) do *not* apply. `shell=True` starts additional process (`%COMSPEC%`) and it changes [how the executable is searched](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24789749/4279) and it changes [what characters should be escaped (what characters are metacharacters)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867015/4279) — do not use `shell=True` unless necessary.