# Subprocess returns exit status 1

Tags: python, subprocess, peewee

When I run a command through subprocess I get exit status 1 without my print or the error raised.

here is my code:

```
    def generate_model(self):
        if not ((self.username == None) or (self.password == None) or (self.database == None)):
            cmd = "python -m pwiz -e %s -H %s -u %s -P %s %s > %s"%(self.engine,self.host,self.username,self.password,self.database,self.database+".py")
            print subprocess.check_call(cmd)
        else:
            raise ValueError
```

command asks an input once terminal is opened. After that it closes with `exit status 1`

When I run the same command directly in command prompt it works fine

Comment: Did you try putting your command inside an array with each string separate ? i.e `['python', '-m', 'pwiz']`... You can use `shlex.split` also.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, even that returns `exit code 1`

Comment: The advise @Idos gave is a really good one, since it is required to prevent command injection. Never construct commands as strings. To solve the problem you should print `cmd` and run the program. Using `>` redirection might need `shell=True` to be set for `check_call()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.check_call()` does not run the shell by default and therefore the redirection operator `>` won't work. To redirect stdout, pass `stdout` parameter instead:

```
with open(filename, 'wb', 0) as file:
    check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pwiz', '-e', ...], stdout=file)
```

Related: [Python subprocess.check_output(args) fails, while args executed via Windows command line work OK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28460506/4279).