# Passing a list to a subprocess call

Tags: python, subprocess, call, robocopy

I have a problem with trying to pass a list into a subprocess call command. I am trying to call the windows robocopy function, passing a list of file types that it should filter by.

```
filter_list = ['*.txt', '*.dat']
call(["robocopy", src, dst, filter_list, "/e"])
```

So passing the list itself does not work the output from robocopy showed that it was trying to find the file type "*.txt*.dat" as if the whole list were a single file type.

I then tried the following

```
call(["robocopy", src, dst, ','.join(filter_list), "/e"])
```

However that gave the same output as my first attempt. Does anyone know how to pass in a list and have it properly divided? Any help is much appriciated!

Comment: Can you try `call(["robocopy", src, dst, " ".join(filter_list), "/e"])` ?

Comment: @StianOK still the same kind of result. Robocopy is now taking a filetype filter of "*.txt *.dat"

Answer (score 4):

You should actually pass the arguments in the list:

```
args = ["robocopy", src, dst]
args.extend(filter_list)
args.append("/e")
call(args)
```

Comment: Ahh, the append and extend were things that I did not know about. Many thanks, that seems to have worked! :)

Comment: `robocopy` name suggests that OP uses Windows where the list is converted to a string for `CreateProcess` i.e., it is *not* passed directly as `argv`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian — That's a good point. I removed the part about `argv`. Even on Windows, Python ensures that arguments are properly quoted, though, right?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: "properly quoted" may be defined by each individual program on Windows. Python uses quoting rules used by some C programs on Windows. [Follow links in this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867015/4279)