# Configure GitPython to output/log commands and process output

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm using GitPython to run several simple commands against repos. Essentially most of it is just:

```py
repo = Repo(repo_dir)
repo.git.fetch()
result = repo.git.diff("origin", name_only=True)
repo.git.merge()
# ...
```

Is there some way to setup GitPython to output/log the commands that are run, and also display the raw output they produce?

For example, the above I would expect to be something along the lines of:

```sh
$ git fetch
$ git diff --name-only origin
path/to/differing_file
path/to/another/differing_file
$ git merge
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GitPython` uses the module `logging`. By adding `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)` before your code, it prints logs like

```
DEBUG:git.cmd:Popen(['git', 'fetch'], cwd=E:\path\foo, universal_newlines=False, shell=None)
```

If you want it to print formatted logs as you expect, you could modify `GitPython`'s source code. I'm using Python 2.7 and my `GitPython` is installed at `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\git`. You can run `git.__file__` in REPL to find your installation directory. In the file `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py`, you can find a method `def execute`. It calls `subprocess.Popen` to run the command. You can modify the line `log.debug` before `Popen` or just insert `print(' '.join(cmd))` at a proper line. If you are using Python 3.3 or newer, you could also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14837250/6330106) on how to print the command with `subprocess`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also:

```
pull = self.repo.git.pull('--rebase')
log.info(pull)
```